# PHP - make all caps?

Tags: php, string

I am not a PHP programmer but have tweaked some in the past.  How can I add something to this block of code to get company, street, and city to be all caps?

```
    protected function getCommonOrderValues($order) 
{
    $shippingAddress = !$order->getIsVirtual() ? $order->getShippingAddress() : null;
    $billingAddress = $order->getBillingAddress();

    return array(
        $shippingAddress ? $shippingAddress->getData("company") : '',
        $shippingAddress ? $shippingAddress->getName() : '', '', '',
        $shippingAddress ? $shippingAddress->getData("street") : '', '', '',
        $shippingAddress ? $shippingAddress->getData("city") : '',
        $shippingAddress ? $shippingAddress->getRegionCode() : '',
        $shippingAddress ? $shippingAddress->getData("postcode") : '',
        $shippingAddress ? $shippingAddress->getCountry() : '', 'standard',
        $order->getRealOrderId(),
        $shippingAddress ? $shippingAddress->getData("telephone") : '', '',
    );
}
```

Comment: Reference: [PHP string functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php)

Comment: -1 This is wasting one's time. Sometimes you can even Google for something, if you search "php all caps" you find strtoupper() as the first result.

Comment: Upvoted for someones unnecessary downvote.

Comment: I repeat that googling "PHP make all caps" which is the exact title of that question returns as the first result "strtoupper()" manual page. This is apparent. -1

Comment: A sidenote: avoid using ternary operators AND php functions inside an array like that. Not only your code will look like garbage, it will be difficult for future maintenance and/or refactoring.

Comment: yes, i found it in google, but i did not know how to correctly integrate.  did it hurt that i asked?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `strtoupper`.

```
$shippingAddress ? $shippingAddress->getData("company") : '',
```

becomes:

```
$shippingAddress ? strtoupper($shippingAddress->getData("company")) : '',
```

Comment: perfect! i found the strtoupper command on my own, but not being a php coder, i did not know how to integrate. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the strtoupper function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP's strtoupper() function. Example:

`strtoupper($shippingAddress->getData("company")),`

Answer (score 0):

```
    protected function getCommonOrderValues($order) 
{
    $shippingAddress = !$order->getIsVirtual() ? $order->getShippingAddress() : null;
    $billingAddress = $order->getBillingAddress();

    return array(
        $shippingAddress ? strtoupper( $shippingAddress->getData("company") ) : '',
        $shippingAddress ? $shippingAddress->getName() : '', '', '',
        $shippingAddress ? strtoupper( $shippingAddress->getData("street") ) : '', '', '',
        $shippingAddress ? strtoupper( $shippingAddress->getData("city") ) : '',
        $shippingAddress ? $shippingAddress->getRegionCode() : '',
        $shippingAddress ? $shippingAddress->getData("postcode") : '',
        $shippingAddress ? strtoupper( $shippingAddress->getCountry()  ): '', 'standard',
        $order->getRealOrderId(),
        $shippingAddress ? $shippingAddress->getData("telephone") : '', '',
    );
}
```

Comment: Why change best answer to another answer ? :D

Comment: sorry, new here.  seems like other answer arrived 2 min before you but i missed it.  i will make sure to choose first "best" answer correctly next time.